# PHP and a weird error in my own function

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
function change_case($str, $type) {
    return str'.$type.'($str);
}
change_case('String', 'tolower');
```

It returns a parse error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  PHP variables need to start with `$`, and `.` is used for concatenation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use a variable function, you build the function name and put it in a variable first, then call it like so (use `function_exists()` in case someone passes an invalid type):

```
function change_case($str, $type) {
    $func = 'str' . $type;

    if (function_exists($func))
        return $func($str);
    else
        return $str;
}
```

No idea why you'd want to write such a function for `strtolower()` and `strtoupper()` though. Even if you wanted a custom function to cover both `lower` and `upper`, a variable function call is unnecessary.

Comment: I use that function, because there is no support for cyrillic letters for ucfirst.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating a function to call a single built-in PHP function? This seems completely backwards and will never, ever be worth the trouble. You can fix your problem by using the built-in PHP functions `strtolower` or `strtoupper`.

Comment: The practice of calling a native method from within a custom method is legitimate, especially if you plan on providing further customized results from the native functions. Remember, the OP asked how to do something, not whether the example was a good idea or not :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do should be done like so:

```
function change_case($str, $type) {
  $function = 'str'.$type;
  if(function_exists($function)){
    return $function($str);
  }
}
```